# Use await like for the subscribe in angular service

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have `this-is-service.service.ts`

```
@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ThisIsService {
    header = new HttpHeaders({
        'Authorization': TOKEN,
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    });
    constructor(
        private http: HttpClient
    ) { }

    getFunction() {
        return this.http.get(API_URL , { headers: this.header })
            .pipe(
                catchError(err => this.handleError(err))
            );
    }


    private handleError(error: HttpErrorResponse) {
        return throwError(error);
    }
}
```

In my `component.ts`

```
variable: any;

constructor(
        private serviceService: ThisIsService
    ) { }

ngOnInit() {
        
    this.serviceService.getFunction().subscribe(
        (resp) => {
            if (resp['success'])
                    this.variable = resp['data'];
        } 
    );
   console.log(this.variable);
}
```

The problem is `console.log` is now being called without finishing the service and ends up printing the value `variable` = `undefined`.

How will I use `await` (or any alternative method) in this kind of setup?

I want the service to finish first before proceeding to the next function. Thanks

Comment: You can use the .toPromise methods of rxjs https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/utility/topromise or define all the action inside the subscription

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Async/Await are used with Promises, so you need to first convert it to a promise and then use await keyword. There might be different ways of doing this, but I would keep it simple for usage:

```
ariable: any;

constructor(
        private serviceService: ThisIsService
    ) { }

ngOnInit() {
    this.getData();
}

async getData() {
   try {
    const resp = await this.serviceService.getFunction().toPromise();
    console.log(resp);
   } catch(e) {
     console.log(`Error: ${e}`);
   }
       
   console.log(this.variable);
}
```

Comment: resp becomes now `ZoneAwarePromise`:
the structure becomes:

`__zone_symbol__value: {/*data I retrieve form the service*/}`

when I add
`this.variable = resp.__zone_symbol__value`

the value is just `[]`. How will add the `resp` to `this.variable`?

Comment: It was typo , I've added the correct one. Please check this one. You can also use then on resp, so I thought you might add it.  whenever the promise will resolve you can get the values. But async/await is better and I have added the same code.